# MongoShell db query of string date is not working

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to query my database on the **date_recorded** field, but the query give zero results.  I'm using the MongoShell and have also tried it in Compass.

I've tried variations of **$eq** with *ISODate* and *Date*:

```js
db.my_collection.find({ "date_recorded": { "$eq":  new ISODate("2017-06-09T01:27:33.967Z") }}).count()
```

I have also tried variations of **$gte** with *ISODate* and *Date*:

```js
db.my_collection.find({ "date_recorded": { "$gte":  new Date("2017-06-09T01:27:33.967Z") }}).count()
```

Record is in the db, notice the highlighted field

[image: Record is in the db, notice the highlighted field]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @JohnnyHK said, the `date_recorded` is a string. To make a comparison, we either need to convert `date_recorded` to a date or compare is with a string.

**The following queries can get us the expected output:**

```
db.my_collection.find({ 
    "date_recorded": { 
        $eq:"2017-06-09T01:27:33.967Z" 
    }
}).count()
```

```
db.my_collection.find({ 
    $expr:{
        $eq:[
            {
                $toDate:"$date_recorded"
            },
            new ISODate("2017-06-09T01:27:33.967Z")
        ]
    }
}).count()
```